# Samba authentification using read-only LDAP

Tags: samba, openldap

We have a read-only `OpenLDAP` server which is used for a variety of authentification services. I am currently trying to add a (standalone) `samba` server to that list which is only to be used as a storage space for backups. There is no need for anything besides the basic username/password authentification.

The incredible long list of tutorials and howtos all assume a newly configured `LDAP` server with full access. While I have the admin credentials for the server and it already contains all the users and the populated samba scheme, the `LDAP` server is merely a read-only mirror.

Currently my configuration ...

```
# LDAP Settings
   passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://192.168.100.11
   ldap suffix = dc=our-domain,dc=de
   ldap user suffix = ou=people
   ldap admin dn = cn=adminacc,ou=daemonadmins,dc=our-domain,dc=de
   ldap ssl = no
   ldap passwd sync = yes
```

...fails with:

```
smbd version 4.2.14-Debian started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2014
[2017/01/13 12:52:49.367065,  0] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:313(smbldap_search_domain_info)
  smbldap_search_domain_info: Adding domain info for SBACKUP failed with NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
[2017/01/13 12:52:49.367106,  0] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap.c:6534(pdb_ldapsam_init_common)
  pdb_init_ldapsam: WARNING: Could not get domain info, nor add one to the domain. We cannot work reliably without it.
[2017/01/13 12:52:49.367116,  0] ../source3/passdb/pdb_interface.c:179(make_pdb_method_name)
  pdb backend ldapsam:ldap://192.168.100.11 did not correctly init (error was NT_STATUS_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO)
```

which is of course not surprising. This server is not known to the `LDAP` and since it is read-only a new entry can't be created. I fail to understand why it is necessary to add any information about the machine in the first place. Is there a certain way smb needs to be configured to cope with read-only access to `LDAP`?

If I explicitly set a `netbios name` in my `smb.conf` which matches the one existing entry on the `LDAP` server everything works fine. But this somewhat feels like a hack and I would prefer to not change the `netbios name`

---

This is somewhat similar to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/410138/samba-read-only-ldap-additional-local-users) which unfortunately only covers the possibility of using a read-only server and not the implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

`samba` NEEDS to be read-write on `LDAP` in order to add/modify machines, trust accounts and a few local users really necessary for a domain to work (admin, nobody and the domain admins and-so-like-groups).

The workaround is: install a OpenLDAP on the samba PDC, have a replicated branch (let's say: `ou=people`) from you master `LDAP` on read-only; use the `glue` overlay to apply this branch under a read-write tree with branches `ou=users` (local users), `ou=groups`, `ou=computers` (self-explanatory).

```
ldap machine suffix = ou=computers
ldap suffix = dc=our-domain,dc=de
# do not set the following; OpenLDAP is
#  able to sort out if a user is a replicated user in 'ou=people'
#  or a local user in 'ou=users'
# ldap group suffix = ou=groups
# ldap user suffix = ou=people
```